# * (tuple of Tensors tensors, name dim, Tensor out)

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have the memory list `list_of_tensors = [tensor1, tensor2, tensor3, tensor4]`. Each element is a pytorch tensor of shape `(1, 1, 84, 84)`.

I want to concatenate that list of tensors to get a tensor of shape `(4, 1, 84, 84)`. `torch.cat(TT, dim=0)` might surely allow me to do that. `TT` must be a tuple of tensor, so `torch.cat(*list_of_tensors, dim=0)` or `torch.cat((*list_of_tensors), dim=0)` won't work.

How can I use `list_of_tensors` and `torch.cat(???, dim=0)` to create a new tensor of shape `(4, 1, 84, 84)`

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular, please rewrite your title after reading that page. The current one isn't clear at all.

Comment: Using `torch.cat` on a list of tensors also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *stack*, and remove surplus dimension with *squeeze*

```
c = (torch.stack(list_of_tensors,dim=1)).squeeze(0)
```

now c.shape is (4, 1, 84, 84)

You can find explanation here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-turn-a-list-of-tensor-to-tensor/8868/6